# How to boot a physical Windows partition with qemu?

Tags: multi-boot, windows, qemu

I have gentoo and windows 7 installed alongside on my only hard drive. I want to start my windows install from within gentoo through qemu. Boot menu works fine but windows bluescreens on me soon after I select it.

How would I make it work?

(I assume windows is missing drivers required for the qemu-emulated hardware to work.)

Comment: make sure that you run `qemu` with correct architecture. Also, windows will fail to boot if it awaits HDD controller to be AHCI and it's not (and vice versa).

Comment: Architecture is good, but I don't think there's anything one can do about the ahci since qemu doesn't seem to support it ...

Comment: Try this: http://www.avforums.com/forums/windows-7/944905-windows-7-ahci.html#post8951321

Comment: @gelraen the problems is that your link describes the reverse process of what I want to do. I can't risk just trying it out without knowing that there is a chance it working out or at least that it's 100% reversible.

Comment: That post is exactly about reverting back from AHCI to ATA. And you always can turn off AHCI on physical machine and change it back, or even simply backup registry files.

Comment: @gelraen in that case please point out a specific post that describes this problem. The one you like initially asks my question but he never receives a response. Also, turning ahci off in my physical machine is not an options since my gentoo (and my performace) depends on it. Also, what do you mean by just backing up registry files exactly? I'm afraid your suggestion is a bit too general for me. I'm just not sure what to do ...

Comment: Just curious... does it have to be QEMU? Or, can VMware be used? I know VMware will boot existing partitions, but I'm not sure about VirtualBox or Bochs.

Answer (score 16):

Booting an native, physical *Windows 7* partition can be done by this:

1. Prepare requisites (*Windows 7* installation media, Virtio drivers).
2. Make your hard drive accessible read-only for your current user.
3. Boot it using QEMU in snapshot mode.

This does not change *anything* on the physical drive (in fact it is read-only). If you want to persist the stuff, remove `-snapshot` from the QEMU invocation or use `commit all` within the QEMU console.

By the way, this works fine for *Windows 10* as well.

---

### Details

#### Prepare requisites

1. Prepare an ISO or, if you have a drive at hand, the real installation media for Win7.
2. Download Virtio drivers, e.g. for example this drivers from Fedora:
   https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/latest-virtio/virtio-win.iso

Take care to use the correct installation media matching the installed Windows architecture (32bit vs 64bit). The following commands assume a 64bit architecture.

#### Make disk accessible

This assumes your hard drive is `/dev/sda` and has be executed as root:

```
   chmod g-w /dev/sda
   chgrp $USER /dev/sda
```

This changes will (probably) be lost at next reboot as *udev* will usually recreate all device files.

#### Booting with QEMU

1. This again assumes your hard drive is `/dev/sda`. Networking is disabled:

   ```
    qemu-system-x86_64 -snapshot -m 3G -enable-kvm -usbdevice tablet \
    -drive file=/dev/sda,if=virtio \
    -drive file=<win7-installation-media> \
    -drive file=<virtio-driver-media>,media=cdrom -boot d \
    -net none
   ```
2. Now boot from CD/DVD to start *Windows 7* recovery, load the Virtio driver and run the following command in the recovery command prompt. Ensure that you replace the drive letters with the proper ones:

   ```
    dism /image:g:\ /add-driver /driver:e:\viostor\w7\amd64
   ```

Drive `G:` is the drive containing your *Windows 7* installation. Drive `E:` represent the CDROM drive with the Virtio drivers.
In order to show some help for this command variant use `dism /image:g:\ /?`.

The `dism` command was copied from [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1177806/384548).

*[I am sorry, screenshots were prepared, but I was unable to post them due to the 10 reputation threshold. Unfortunately I am unable to find them in the meantime :(]*

Comment: The 10 reputation thing is a pain. It stopped me, and a lot of others, from giving the detailed kind of help we wanted. =/ I just uploaded mine to imgur and pasted the links, FYI.

Comment: To be honest, 10 points are not too hard to get. The issue is that I am not able to find the screenshots anymore. I am pretty sure that they are somewhere on my disks, but ... :/

Comment: Can it be read/write?

Comment: Sure. Don't forget to remove `-snapshot` if you actually want to persist the stuff.

Comment: I've used a Windows 7 ISO and could not get the DISM command to work. Got errors 2, 87 and 200 and something... the only way to get the virtio drivers installed was to proceed with the installation until the drive selection UI and use the "Install Drivers" button to graphically search and install them, then cancel the wizard and go back to the console.

Comment: A quick update: I also managed to get the drivers installed with `drvload.exe E:\amd64\w7\viostor.inf`

Comment: As far as I understand, `drvload` installs the driver to the *current* Windows installation, which maybe differs from your use case. In case you boot from the installation media/recovery to install the drivers for your regular installation, you will need the `dism` variant. Anyway, +1 for the useful hint.

Comment: I didn't realize I could do `chmod /dev/...`. That was the missing piece of the puzzle for me.

Answer (score 7):

I have managed to do this on archlinux, mostly by adapting examples that other (smarter) people provided in blogs.

**Minimal Version:**

install deps

```
sudo pacman -S qemu   # qemu itself
sudo pacman -S ovmf   # intel EFI driver
cp /usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd bios.bin   # copy OVMF_CODE.fd to bios.bin somewhere. It MUST be renamed.
```

start qemu

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm                                   `# enable KVM optimiations` \
    -L .                                          `# dir with bios.bin` \
    --bios bios.bin                               `# bios.bin itself` \
    -m 8G                                         `# provide reasonable amount of ram` \
    -cpu host                                     `# match the CPU type exactly` \
    -drive file=/dev/sda,format=raw,media=disk    `# load raw HDD`
```

**Performance Optimizations**

The following flags were also recommended to me, and I have been using them successfully.

```
# emulate exact host cpu,
# enable hyper-v enlightenments
-enable-kvm
-cpu host,hv_relaxed,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff,hv_vapic,hv_time
-machine type=pc,accel=kvm

# use all available CPU cores
-smp $(nproc)
```

**Viewer**

I used spice as a viewer:

```
-daemonize  `# don't start monitor, we connect using RDP` \
-vga qxl \
-spice port=5930,disable-ticketing \
-device virtio-serial \
-device virtserialport,chardev=spicechannel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=spicechannel0,name=vdagent \
```

Followed by the following to display viewer

```
spicy -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5930 & disown spicy;  # spice-gtk
```

**Windows Bootloader Warning**

Finally, beware of the windows bootloader if you are using multiple disks. I have a windows-install now that will not boot unless a second non-OS drive is also present.

**References**

I wish I kept my sources here - I remember at least the following were super helpful:

https://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page
https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU
https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_kvm/data/part_2_book_book_kvm.html

Good Luck!

Comment: This worked for me on arch linux

Comment: Very helpful, I've got a basic case working. My next challenge is to try and get my old physical Windows XP C: drive to run using as a real root disk inside qemu.

Answer (score 4):

From what I saw in [this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-qemu-to-boot-a-full-hardware-installed-windows-partion-on-dual-boot-system-944482/), you can't use qemu to boot an existing installation of Windows.

The primary argument being given is that, when windows is installed the Product key is associated with the Motherboard of your computer. Now, when you try to run Windows using qemu, windows perceives qemu emulator as a different motherboard and thus gives problems.

Refer to [the post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-qemu-to-boot-a-full-hardware-installed-windows-partion-on-dual-boot-system-944482/) for more details.

Comment: VirtualBox can advertise itself as arbitrary motherboard (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=33356) perhaps QEMU can as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use for a physical Windows 10 drive.  Note that in many cases Windows will fail to boot if you don't use the "`-cpu host`" flag.

Just replace `/dev/nvme0n1` with your drive eg. `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`

```sh
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 8 -m 8192 -drive format=raw,file=/dev/nvme0n1  # Replace this last parameter
```

[Source](http://realtechtalk.com/QEMUKVM_wont_boot_Windows_2016_or_2019_server_on_an_Intel_Core_i3_-2221-articles).