# I could not run a macOS physical partition from my died Mac mini with QEMU on my supercomputer for rescuing my files

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mac, partitioning, qemu

I am an Arch Linux user. I learned from [How to boot a physical Windows partition with qemu?](https://superuser.com/questions/342719/how-to-boot-a-physical-windows-partition-with-qemu.I) used the QEMU settings from the [repo's shell script file](https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM/blob/master/basic.sh) and modified to:

```bsh
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm \
    -m 8G \
    -machine q35,accel=kvm \
    -smp cores=4,threads=4,sockets=1 \
    -cpu Penryn,vendor=GenuineIntel,kvm=on,+sse3,+sse4.2,+aes,+xsave,+avx,+xsaveopt,+xsavec,+xgetbv1,+avx2,+bmi2,+smep,+bmi1,+fma,+movbe,+invtsc \
    -device isa-applesmc,osk="$OSK" \
    -smbios type=2 \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file="$OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd" \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file="$OVMF/OVMF_VARS-1024x768.fd" \
    -vga virtio \
    -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-output \
    -usb -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse \
    -device qemu-xhci,id=xhci -device usb-host,bus=xhci.0,vendorid=0x14cd,productid=0x6116 \
    -netdev user,id=net0 \
    -device e1000-82545em,netdev=net0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:c9:18:27 \
    -device ich9-ahci,id=sata \
    -drive id=ESP,if=none,format=qcow2,file=ESP.qcow2 \
    -device ide-hd,bus=sata.2,drive=ESP \
    -drive id=SystemDisk,if=none,file=/dev/sdf \
    -device ide-hd,bus=sata.4,drive=SystemDisk \
```

And my HD's `fdisk`:

```bsh
Disk /dev/sdf: 465,78 GiB, 500107860992 bytes, 976773166 sectors
Disk model: Storage Device  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D61073AE-0D2D-40E6-BEBB-6D80D02E3E36

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdf1         40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sdf2     409640 975503591 975093952   465G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sdf3  975503592 976773127   1269536 619,9M Apple boot
```

I have received the error:

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for '/dev/sdf' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1090:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1090:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
audio: Failed to create voice `dac'
```

I also tried to use the setting `-drive id=SystemDisk,if=none,file=/dev/sdf,format=raw,media=disk \`, but no luck.

Comment: idk much about qemu, but are you sure it can read & write HFS+?

Comment: Yes, it does on Linux.